# SSRS mysterious extra pages

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

I have two reports that are setup with the same page dimensions- A4 portrait, with page margins of 1cm.

When I run the reports seperately and print them they both come out as expected: fitting into the width constraint of the page.

However, when I include one report as a subreport in the other and then run and print the "master" report I start to experience problems.  Even though both reports appear I get extra blank pages appearing every other page in the output.

I'm sure I'm missing a simple trick - probably with the page sizes of the two reports but I can't figure it out - any pointers?

I don't mind changing the setup of the subreport as it will never be run as a seperate eport in the wild, I only included that step to prove that it did indeed fit within the page!

Answer (score 6):

One thing that might help is to set your right margin to 0 in your master report.  I've noticed this myself with a subreport that appears correctly in a master report, and adding it as a subreport in another master causes it to insert extra page breaks.  I agree with TheTXI, its very frustrating, I wish they had a debug/inspection mode like firebug does for web pages.

Edit: 
Also you should check your fields to make sure they aren't set to expand automatically (unintended).  Right click, properties, set `.CanGrow = False`

Comment: I have struggled w/ this issue on many reports for a long time.   This may actually be the silver bullet.  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 5):

There is probably an overhang somewhere with your page size or margins that is causing it to spill over into blank pages. They can be infuriating to find sometimes.

Comment: Even though the two reports (both the master and sub) will print correctly when run individually?

Should the page size of the sub report be smaller than, or the same as the master report?

Thanks

Comment: What we'll usually do is something like this:

subreport:
page size = body size = body size of master report
no margins
master:
page size = _____
margins = ____
body size = page size - margins

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the report's ConsumeContainerWhitespace property to true for all report acting in master report!

Comment: I dont find this makes a difference

Answer (score 2):

See page 12 of [this document](http://preview.tinyurl.com/5pxzeq) (.doc download).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that it is a word document... a very good one though.

Comment: wink...*(.doc download)* wink.wink.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old thread, but I recently had this problem and found another reason why you might end up with blank pages- if there is any whitespace in the master report, the PDF renderer creates a blank page.

So, if you have not found the solution in the above measures, make sure that your master report has no white space. The size of each doesn't seem to matter. What matters is that your subreport is the same size as your master report and that the subreport starts at coordinates 0,0.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue where every second page was blank on my report. I tried all the suggestions I could find with no relief. I reduced the column widths until the report only took up half the page, still had blank pages, which also told me it wasn't column widths causing my problems.

Finally, by setting the right margin to 0, the problem is now resolved. Thanks Snives! It makes no sense, but that's not important right now!